# TRIAC T435-600B issue with solenoid pump and diode

Tags: diodes, triac, solenoid

I'm currently facing an issue with controlling a solenoid pump using a T435-600B TRIAC in a configuration that includes a diode.

The power supply for both the TRIAC and the pump is the same, and it's triggered by an opto. I am unable to control the pump when the diode is connected in series with the solenoid pump coil (connected at JSx5).

However, when I tested a similar setup with a solenoid valve and without the diode, it worked as expected. Could it be the phase shift between voltage and current due to the coil of the solenoid?

[image]

I'm not sure what is causing this issue or how to resolve it. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this situation? I'm open to ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing the solution I found for this problem. The problem comes from the phase shift of voltage/current due to the coil and the diode, as well as the non-zero-crossing optocoupler. The triac is activated by current, and with the phase shift, it activates in the middle of the sinusoid. Due to the zero-crossing photocoupler and the half-wave caused by the diode, there is not even a quarter of a wave left to power the coil.

To solve this problem, I have found several solutions:

- Place a return diode with a resistor (very bad idea)
- Replace the triac with a relay (good idea, but not in my case)
- Replace the optocoupler with another zero-crossing one (bingo!)

I hope this can be of some help to someone.